# How to resize the label size by button name length

Tags: c#, winforms, label, size

I am trying to create buttons and labels dynamically, creating is fine but resizing of label is problem, i want to scale label size by button name length but resizing does not work, my code and screen shot of output are below, can you help me please?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{


    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Name = "btnAdi" + (i + 1).ToString();
    btn.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
    btn.Location = new Point(0, btn.Height * i);

    Label lbl = new Label()
    {
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
        Dock = DockStyle.None,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
    };
    lbl.Text = btn.Name.ToString();

    lbl.Size = new Size( (btn.Name.Length), btn.Height);
    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    lbl.Location = new Point(btn.Width, (btn.Height * i));


}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: It's not working, as the size you assing is too small. the size is in pixel, not in "char space width".

Comment: @Malior is there a way to convert it to pixel ? (this is the answer i am expecting)

Comment: You may want to learn about `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You just have to autosize the label, something like this:**

**EDIT:**

Following @Malior comment, with autosize you can remove the "lbl.Size" line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Name = "btnAdi" + (i + 1).ToString();
    btn.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
    btn.Location = new Point(0, btn.Height * i);

    Label lbl = new Label()
    {
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
        Dock = DockStyle.None,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
    };
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Text = btn.Name.ToString();

    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    lbl.Location = new Point(btn.Width, (btn.Height * i));
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT2:**

If you want with the property "lbl.Size" you need something like this to get the width of the lbl.Text:

```
Font arialBold = new Font("Arial", 10);
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lbl.Text, arialBold);
lbl.Size = new Size(size.Width, size.Height);
```

I have noted that method give 1 or 2 spaces more that was supposed too.

**Output2:**

[image]

Comment: In this case, i guess you can leave out the lvl.Size = assignment.

Comment: I just realized that this does not solve actual problem, my problem is why lbl.size did not work?, now label size scaled by AutoSize property not by Size property, so problem still exist in my case.

Comment: I guess I have understood the problem, i'm going to edit with a new solution. btw, I guess the AutoSize was the best way to follow.

Comment: @Mikev Thank you for reply, so i need Text, Font name and Font size to convert it to pixel then Size property will work. But you say AutoSize property does all these things. Thank you for help, i am learning programing this helps me to understand concepts.